# Dll is Published site, but missing in Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build

Should be a tiny issue of something overlooked, but I have been stuck on this one since days now and need some pointers here.

We are on .NET 3.5, VS2008 and TFS 2010

I have a ASP.NET Web Site project. The Solution has multiple class projects, and one website project.

Issue is that when TFS builds the project, then 2 dlls never get generated in the _PublishedWebsite folder.

Strange thing is that these dlls are generated and present outside the _PublsihedWebsite folder, but not in the bin, inside publishedwebsites.

If we publish the website, then also everything is perfect, and all DLL come.

Rogue dlls are:
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

I have tried setting the CopyLocal of these dlls in all the projects.

e.g.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.30729.4402, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Library\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I have checked that my bin folder has a refresh file with the path correctly mentioned to my Library folder where this dll is physically placed.

Here is a high level view of my solution structure:

```
Project 1
 ----Refers to Report DLL (CopyLocal is true)

Project 2
 ----Refers to Report DLL (CopyLocal is true)

Website project
  -----Refers to Project 1
  -----Refers to Project 2
  ----Refers to Report DLL (via Library folder in the refresh file in Bin folder)
```

What else can I check?

Answer (score 2):

Please set the logging level of your build definition to Detailed, run a TFS build again and inspect your detailed logs, both in the TFS build explorer and the MSBuild log file in the drop location. I suspect there will be the key to the problem. For example, i've seen the ASP.NET precompiler to give errors generating websites, while this is not displayed in the build explorer logs that clear.

Comment: That's one new idea for me. Let me try it out and report back here.

Comment: The log seems to hint that becuase the dll is i nthe GAC, hence it was not copied. This is not what I need. I had set it to CopyLocal becuase i need it to get dropped inside publishedwebsite folder